# Email thumbnail could not be retrieved under Individual Email results

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, images, marketingcloudapi

We have Marketing Cloud connected to Sales Cloud connected with MC Connect.  Now these emails are shown as Individual Email Results in Sales Cloud. All works well but the problem is its not showing the Email Thumbnail under it.

I have attached the screenshot.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the remote site was not configured for cloud marketing.